# Custom fields multiple values, Wordpress, PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to this with `php`, but working to learn, and i can't figure this out.

Here goes the original code with one value i get working:

```
$description = get_post_meta($post->ID, "description", false);

if ($description[0]=="") { 

<!-- If there are no custom fields, show nothing -->

 } else { 

<div class="wrap">
    <h3>Products</h3>

     foreach($description as $description) {
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    } 

</div>

 }
```

I have difficulties to modify this code to retrive values from more then one custom field input and putting it out together and inbetween the same .

Here is code with one more value added, but im uncearten how to combine thoose 2 values:

```
$description = get_post_meta($post->ID, "Description", false);
$seccond_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, "price", false);

<?php
if ($description[0]=="") {  
?>
<strong> how do i combine 2 values here?</strong>


<!-- If there are no custom fields, show nothing -->
<?php
 } else { 

?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h3>products</h3>


<strong>// how does this part work and how to i combine 2 values here?</strong>
<?php
     foreach($description as $description) {
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }  
?>
</div>

 }
```

Maybe someone here has a good tip for a good sajt that covers my questions above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($description[0] != "" && $seccond_value[0] != "") { 

// Combine two values and print them


} else {

// Value is not set

}
```